# Daterangepicker for bootstrap show modal cannot set dateformat

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, daterangepicker

I have daterangepicker inside bootstrap modal,
and i want to set dateformat = 'DD-MM-YYYY'

```
$('#dateinsidemodal').daterangepicker({
     format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
     singleDatePicker: true,
     calender_style: "picker_3"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
     console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    });
```

but dateformat itsnot work.
its always show on default format = MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: What is the version and URL of daterangepicker you are using ?

Comment: Where i can see the version? ,  http://www.daterangepicker.com/ , Thax Gangadhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write format like below:

```
locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        }
```

In your case:

```
$('#dateinsidemodal').daterangepicker({
     locale: {
             format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
     }
     singleDatePicker: true,
     calender_style: "picker_3"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
     console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    });
```

Comment: @onyseven welcome! And it is `Pathik` not `Pathix` :)

Comment: upps , sorry , btw thanx again Pathik :)